# postgres Foreign Key to only accept table names

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres, and I want to log new changes in several of my tables. I want to have a column which will only take on values which are table names, so that I can have a column for table, column for id, and column for date that that value was updated.

I see that all the table names are in the table information_schema.tables. Is it possible to use that as a foreign key, or would that be inadvisable?

Comment: because the data in the tables is fairly important, and I don't want to accidentally cause any issues by doing something that the Postgres developers didn't intend

Comment: why is this in production?

Comment: yes, this is in production